# How does Google's Sign On Work? OAuth2.0? SAML?

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on, google-authentication

I am curious about how Google's Authentication works. Does it use OAuth2.0 for Authorization? Or SAML for authentication? I tried intercepting the requests and responses, but I cannot determine how their authentication/authorization flow works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Signing in with a Google Account is based on OpenID Connect (OIDC). Google produces wrappers (libraries..) that do a lot of useful things on top of plain protocol. From Google's OIDC [page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect):

> If you want to provide a "Sign-in with Google" button for your website or app, we recommend using Google Sign-In, our sign-in client library that is built on the OpenID Connect protocol and provides OpenID Connect formatted ID Tokens.

G Suite also [supports](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en) SAML for SSO to 3rd party apps. (You still authenticate with your Google Account)